# The co-countable sigma-algebra of a countable set is countably generated

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm self studying Billingsley Probability and Measure (3rd edition). I'm having trouble with exercise 2.11 b the reverse direction:

Show that if $\Omega$ is countable, then the sigma-algebra $\mathscr{F}$ consisting of the countable and cocountable subsets of $\Omega$ are countably generated.

The book already provides a hint: it tells me to show that $\mathscr{F}$ is generated by a countable class of singletons. I did this as follows:

$\mathscr{F}=\sigma(\mathscr{A})$ with $\mathscr{A}$ countable. Let $\mathscr{A}=\{A_1,A_2,\ldots\}$. Then the $A_i$ are countable or cocountable. Take $S$ as the singletons $\{\omega\}$ with $\omega \in A_i^*$, where $A_i^*=A_i$ if $A_i$ is countable and $A_i^*=A_i^c$ if $A_i$ is cocountable. Then because the $A_i^*$ are countable and $\mathscr{A}$ is countable $S$ is countable. We have that $\mathscr{A} \subseteq \sigma(S)$, take the unions of the singletons to get the $A_i^*$ back and take complements if needed to get the $A_i$. It follows that $\sigma(\mathscr{A}) \subseteq \sigma(S)$. But we also have $\sigma(S) \subseteq \sigma(\mathscr{A})=\mathscr{F}$: performing a countable amount of set operations on a countable amount of singletons produce countable sets. Thus $\mathscr{F}=\sigma(S)$.

**My question:** is this correct and how can I show (hint of the book) that $\mathscr{F}$ consists of the sets $B$ and $B\cup\Omega_0^c$ with $B\subseteq \Omega_0$, where $\Omega_0$ is the union of the singletons in $S$?